# Message from seller

Tags: sentence, foreign-phrases

I recently did DM a seller for a product in the English language, I asked:

"Hello, I'm interested in one of your products. Can you tell me the price of this item?"

the seller is Chinese and replies with:

"But (placeholder for product) is one the producing by factory"

What is meant with this exactly?

Comment: If that is the answer, what was the question? 
The sentence is nonsensical, but we *might* be able to guess what they meant if you provide more context. It would still be a guess though.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks I edited the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not up to us to guess what a non-native speaker might mean when they try to use English - especially in an interaction where *neither* party is a native Anglophone.

Comment: What does DM mean? (Don’t tell me, I’ve already decided to vote to close.) First rule of communication, don’t use obscure abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

It's my guess:

> The product is the one produced by the factory.

and I think he wanted you to ask this question from the product owner (for example the factory) or another person!
:/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added more details. Will this change your answer?

Comment: I'm sure you're right in saying that he meant "But the product is the one produced by the factory." because european language verb tenses are really difficult for speakers of most Chinese  languages since Chinese verbs don't really have tenses in the same way as european languages. However the reply doesn't make much sense as an answer to the question anyway. I think the seller misunderstood the question.